# QGIS Viewshed plugin not in any menu

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed

Running QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich on Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa.  Just tried to add the Viewshed/Visibility Analysis plugin and the Plugin Manager shows it as installed, but it's not in the plugin menu (or any other that I can find). No error messages relating to this have popped up.

Any ideas on how to get this up & running?

Answer (score 4):

Visibility Analysis plugin adds the related tools to Processing Toolbox as in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've found it there now, got it. It used to be in the plugins menu but haven't used it for a good while: https://www.giscourse.com/how-to-create-a-visibility-analysis-with-qgis/  Quote "in QGIS you can carry out a visibility analysis via Viewshed Analysis plugin. After you install it you can access this tool by going to Plugins > Viewshed Analysis > Advanced viewshed analysis."